# Can't import file dumped by mysqldump

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, mysql-error-1064

I created a dump from a database that we have on a kube pod as follows:

```
kubectl exec mysql-0 -n pod-name --  mysqldump -u root -ppass dbname >  ~/Desktop/dump.sql
```

I then try to import this database into my local db by:

```
mysql ebdb --force -uroot -proot < ~/Desktop/dump.sql
```

But I keep getting errors as:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 4550: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''---\nid: 195\nrestaurant_id: 4330\napi_key: sk_live_wVi93Gt11111puIE\nm' at line 1
```

I repeated the dumping and importing multiple times with similar errors: syntax problems.

I thought maybe the error has to do with encoding, so I dumped using

```
kubectl exec mysql-0 -n pod-name --  mysqldump -u root -ppass --default-character-set=utf8 ebdb >  ~/Desktop/dump.sql
```

but still same error.

Any ideas about what might be going wrong here?

**p.s**: Of course I'm changing the name of the pod and pass here as well as some of the chars in the api key for obvious reasons. Otherwise things are left as is

Comment: Hi mrateb, try `mysqldump -u root -ppass --create-options DBNAME > ~/Desktop/dump.sql`.

Comment: Have you ever opened the dump with a text editor and took a look what might be wrong?

Comment: [tag:mysql-error-1064] means *SQL syntax error*. The error message shows the text immedately after the last thing MySQL understood. Open up that `dump.sql` file with a text editor, find line 4550 and the surrounding lines, and [edit] your question to show them to us.